# Windows 8 release preview BSODs in Virtual box

Tags: 10.04, virtualbox, windows-8

I have an Ubuntu 10. 04 and Windows 7 installed on computer. Now I would like to try Windows 8 on virtual box OSE. I  have a Windows 8 release preview ISO disk in a pendrive and added IDE primary slave as it

```
  IDE Primary Slave (CD/DVD):   
Windows8-ReleasePreview-32bit-English.iso (1.64 GB)
```

This is my Windows 8 virtual box settings.

[image]

And what I see when I start Windows 8 is

[image]

What is the problem? My system RAM is 2.00 GB where 1.85 is usable? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I gave you an answer below but generally we can not answer questions on non-Ubuntu guest operating systems here. It may be borderline case as settings in the host are involved but still I vote for closing as off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install an operating system with a PAE kernel you need to enable this in the settings for your guest OS:

[image]